# Get boolean vector for indices

Tags: r

How to get a index vector which represents if one element of `b` is placed in `a`?

```
a<-sample(1:100,20)
[1]  85  15  84  66  31  67  74  19  54  21  78  61 100   2   5  96  62   3  60  82
a==2
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

But I want a boolean vector for all matches for entries in a with entries in `b=1:10` so the result should look like

```
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `a %in% b` construction.

Comment: right many thx I have used to it that I dont forget it again.